# Tkinter placements not consistent with some other screens

Tags: python, tkinter

I develop some programs with an interface using tkinter with Python. I use `.place(x=10, y=10)` for every `Label` or `Button` whenever I design a simple interface.

The problem is sometimes, when somebody else uses the compiled version of my Python script, the placements get weird and different.

Here's what I designed:

[image: my design]

Versus what the user is seeing:
[image: what others are seeing]

I have intentionally anchored the labels to the right and input boxes to the left so that I can get a perfect "10" x distance. However, I'm not sure why it moves a bit to the left when certain users use the program. Is it screen resolution/ratio?

Can anyone explain why and how could I prevent this in the future?

Comment: _"The problem is sometimes, when somebody else uses the compiled version of my Python script, the placements get weird and different."_ - this is why `place` is not recommended - you have to do all of the work of making sure coordinates are correct for different resolutions and different font sizes.

Comment: I've been switching up screen resolution and ratio but it still looks the same for me. I'm not sure what's really the cause of this problem. How can I make the placements more consistent? `.grid()`?

Comment: In my experience, a combination of `pack` and `grid` makes the most sense.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. When I started learning Python and Tkinter, I went straight ahead using `.place()` than pack and grid. I always thought it was easier.